# I keep getting 404 error when trying to run swagger ui from a(otherwise working) fastapi endpoint (using /docs). What am i doing wrong?

Tags: fastapi, swagger-ui

I am experimenting with fastapi. Created a basic "hello world" api and hosted it on a docker container. When i hit the endpoint URL, i get the desired output [image: Standard output]

However, when i try the same with swagger ui by adding /docs to the end of the url, i get the following error:[image: Error with /docs]

The code is absolutely basic:

`

```
from fastapi import FastAPI, File, UploadFile

app = FastAPI()


@app.get("/")
def read_root():
    'Docstring'
    return {"Hello": "katseye"}
```

`

Am i missing something obvious here?

Comment: Are you sure you path is good ?

it seam like you try to load the doc from a route with a path.

In a basic fastapi app, the doc is on ```server:port/docs```

Comment: The docker container is running on a remote(workplace) instance and not my local machine, hence the url